# Carregamento antes de exibir o conteúdo

Tags: javascript, html

Necessito fazer que uma animação gif seja feita antes de carregar meus gráficos, e depois que o carregamento for feito, a animação para de aparecer, estou usando o Highcharts para a criação dos gráficos, porém não tenho idéia de como fazer esse carregamento, deixarei alguns exemplos aqui, para que vocês possam ter uma noção do que preciso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse seria o carregamento antes do gráfico ser exibido,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de carregado a animação iria desaparecer e ficaria somente o gráfico.

Vou deixar o código fonte de um dos gráficos, eles não tem css pois está em highcharts, e ele é construido totalmente em JS.

```
        <div class="col-lg-6 grid-margin stretch-card">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div>
                                            <div id="container01" style="min-width: 310px; height: 350px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
                                            <script src="js/grafico_preventiva_AxE.js"></script>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

JS:

```
            $.getJSON(baseUrlApi + 'mpreventivasaxe')
            .done(function (response) {

                Highcharts.setOptions({
                    colors: ['#50B432', '#4286f4']
                });

                Highcharts.chart('container01', {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'PREVENTIVAS ABERTAS X EXECUTADAS'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: response.categories,
                        crosshair: true
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Hora Edição'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                        pointFormat:  '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                                      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} </b></td></tr>',
                        footerFormat: '</table>',
                        shared: true,
                        useHTML: true
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            pointPadding: 0.2,
                            borderWidth: 0
                        }
                    },
                    series: response.series
                });
            });
```

Comment: O que você pode fazer é: 1. Exibir a animação antes da requisição; 2. Utilizar o evento [`load`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load) para esconder a animação. Este evento é disparado quando o código carrega o gráfico. Fiz um exemplo básico: https://codepen.io/valdeir2000/pen/MLLYBR

Comment: @ValdeirPsr deu certo, mt obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a opção [`loading`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/loading) do`Highcharts` com um `CSS` personalizado:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    // ...

    loading: {
        labelStyle: {
            backgroundImage: 'url("http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png")',
            display: 'block',
            width: '136px',
            height: '26px',
            backgroundColor: '#000'
        }
    },

    // ...
});
```

Você só precisa colocar a imagem que deseja no atributo `backgroundImage`.

Referência: [**Highcharts loading image**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14690969/3388148).